# Display Data from Four Tables with SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013, delphi-xe8

### Four Tables

I have four tables namely `Candidates`, `Parties`, `Multiplier` and `Votes`.

### Table Layouts with Examples

Here’s the layouts for the tables:

- **Candidates**

E.g.

```
+--------------+----------+----------------+--------+
| Candidate_ID | Surname  |      Name      | Gender |
+--------------+----------+----------------+--------+
|            1 | BAREND   | INNOCK CHARLIE | MALE   |
|            2 | DU PREEZ | DONAVAN GARY   | MALE   |
|            3 | BERTELS  | MEGAN MARIÉ    | FEMALE |
|            4 | HOPLEY   | CAITLIN TAYLOR | FEMALE |
+--------------+----------+----------------+--------+
```

- **Parties**

E.g.

```
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
| Party_ID | Party_Type | Grade | Class |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
| H1       | Head       |       |       |
| T1       | TEACHER    |       |       |
| 8N       | LEARNER    |     8 | N     |
| 9N       | LEARNER    |     9 | N     |
| 10N      | LEARNER    |    10 | N     |
| 11N      | LEARNER    |    11 | N     |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+
```

Note: N ranges between A and J, e.g. 8A, 8B, 8C … 8J.

- **Multiplier**

E.g.

```
+------------+------------+
| Party_Type | Multiplier |
+------------+------------+
| HEAD       |          3 |
| TEACHER    |          2 |
| LEARNER    |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

- **Votes**: ClassA is a vote for a position on the Management Committee, ClassB is a vote for deputy and ClassC is a vote for head, e.g. head girl or boy.

E.g.

```
+--------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Candidate_ID | Party_ID | ClassA | ClassB | ClassC |
+--------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|            1 | H1       |      2 |      2 |      1 |
|            4 | 8C       |     23 |      5 |      2 |
|            2 | H1       |      3 |      2 |      2 |
|            3 | 9D       |     30 |     16 |     10 |
|            1 | T1       |     15 |      7 |      5 |
|            3 | T1       |     17 |     10 |      9 |
|            4 | T1       |      4 |      2 |      1 |
|            2 | 10E      |     24 |     10 |      4 |
+--------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Basically, I am trying to write an SQL statement to tally all the votes for each candidate and then sort the records according to the votes from most to least as follows:

```
+----+----------+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | Surname  |     Names      | ClassA | ClassB | ClassC |
+----+----------+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  3 | BERTELS  | MEGAN MARIÉ    |     96 |     36 |     28 |
|  4 | HOPLEY   | CAITLIN TAYLOR |     64 |     19 |      8 |
|  1 | BAREND   | INNOCK CHARLIE |     36 |     20 |     13 |
|  2 | DU PREEZ | DONAVAN GARY   |     33 |     16 |     10 |
+----+----------+----------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

### My Effort

Thus far I have only been able to tally all the votes without applying the multipliers:

```
SELECT C.Candidate_ID, C.Surname, C.Name, Sum(V.ClassA) AS ClassA, Sum(V.ClassB) AS ClassB, Sum(V.ClassC) AS ClassC
FROM Candidates C INNER JOIN Votes V ON C.Candidate_ID = V.Candidate_ID
GROUP BY C.Candidate_ID, C.Surname, C.Name;
```

### My Problem

So I believe my problem is quite clear: I need to apply the multipliers respectively according to the type of party the votes came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT 
  C.Candidate_ID,
  C.Surname, 
  C.Name, 
  SUM(V.ClassA * M.Multiplier) AS ClassA, 
  SUM(V.ClassB * M.Multiplier) AS ClassB, 
  SUM(V.ClassC * M.Multiplier) AS ClassC
FROM 
  ( ( Candidates C 
      INNER JOIN Votes V ON C.Candidate_ID = V.Candidate_ID )
    INNER JOIN Parties P ON V.Party_ID = P.Party_ID )
  INNER JOIN Multiplier M ON P.Party_Type = M.Party_Type
GROUP BY 
  C.Candidate_ID, 
  C.Surname, 
  C.Name;
```

Comment: I implemented your answer, but unfortunately I received the following syntax error: (missing operator) in query expression 'C.Candidate_ID = V.Candidate_ID INNER JOIN Parties P ON V.Party_ID = P.Party_ID INNER JOIN Multiplier M ON P.Party_Type = M.Party_Typ'.

Comment: Sorry, this needs parentheses. I added them in the answer.

Comment: Eureka! It worked! Thanks a million Hellmar. Would it be any trouble to maybe explain the parentheses to me? O, and how do I sort by Class from most to least?

Comment: I think this is a MS Access limitation. Normally you wouldn't need the parentheses, unless you want to force the joins to be evaluated in a specific order.

Comment: I just implemented the statement in my program and it seems even Delphi requires the parentheses. So lastly, how do I do the sort? And is it possible to proper case the values of `Surname` and `Name`, for e.g. “INNOCK CHARLIE” as “Innock Charlie”?

Comment: A quick search says there is a Access/VBA function StrConv that you can use to capitalize the names. Maybe that works for you too, but I am not a Delphi expert.

Comment: As for the sort, I would add `SORT BY ClassA DESC, ClassB DESC, ClassC DESC` at the end of the query. Please check, if that is what you want?

Comment: Thank you. I'll further investigate how to proper case string values via SQL. I added the `SORT BY`, but unfortunately I receive the syntax error: (missing operator) in query expression 'C.Name SORT BY V.ClassA'.

Comment: Alas, another MS Access limitation. I just see that you cannot use column aliases in the sort expression. So it would have to be `SORT BY SUM(V.ClassA * M.Multiplier) DESC` .. and so forth.

Comment: Well, it's a Microsoft product, so it's expected. Where should I add the above statement? For if I add it at the end of the query, I receive yet again a syntax error reading: (missing operator) in query expression 'C.Surname SORT BY Sum(V.ClassA * M.Multiplier)'.

Comment: Update: I changed `C.Surname` and `C.Name` in the `SELECT` clause to `StrConv(C.Surname, 3) AS Surname` and `StrConv(C.Name, 3) AS Name` and it worked perfectly in both Access and Delphi to convert the string values to proper.

Comment: Whoops. It should be ORDER BY. Getting late.